# Sonarqube Zapscan and Dependency Check

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-scan

I am using sonar zap scan and sonar dependency check plugins, when i run sonar standalone analysis through jenkins , the zap scan report is generated, and when we generate dependency check report for the same project the zap scan report is getting overwritten . is there any solution to get both dependency check and zap report for a project instead of getting overwritten.the below are the properties for project dependency

```
# required metadata  
sonar.projectKey=Project  
sonar.projectName=Project (Dependencies Check)  
sonar.projectVersion=1.0.0  

# optional description  
sonar.projectDescription= Project dependency test results.  

# path to source directories (required)  
sonar.sources=.  

# Encoding of the source code 
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8  

# dependency Report 
sonar.dependencyCheck.reportPath=dependency-check-report.xml
```

the below are the sonar properties for project zap scan

```
# required metadata  
sonar.projectKey=Project  
sonar.projectName=Project  
sonar.projectVersion=1.0.0  

# optional description  
sonar.projectDescription= Project zap test results.  

# path to source directories (required)  
sonar.sources=.  

# Encoding of the source code 
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8  

# ZAP Scan Report  
sonar.zap.reportPath=report/security_report.html
```

We are using sonarqube 5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you're getting is the natural outcome of the procedure you're using.

You cannot "update" an existing analysis. If you want to have data from both reports present in your analysis, you must pass both reports to the analysis. Ex:

```
# required metadata  
sonar.projectKey=Project  
sonar.projectName=Project (Dependencies Check)  
sonar.projectVersion=1.0.0  

# path to source directories (required)  
sonar.sources=.  

# Encoding of the source code 
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8  

# dependency Report 
sonar.dependencyCheck.reportPath=dependency-check-report.xml

# ZAP Scan Report  
sonar.zap.reportPath=report/security_report.html
```

If you really must run these separately, then give them separate keys, which will yield two distinct projects in SonarQube.

Comment: Hi Ann,thanks for your concern, is there any way to generate them using a single project key, i have to run them separately only .

Comment: Sure, run the scans separately, but feed both reports into a single analysis.